# Duplicated rows that doesn't match on Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am doing a query in Laravel, in this query I have to join two tables to obtain information, the problem is that the only parameter where I can join them isn't unique. So when I print the results instead of getting something like

```
a - 1
b - 2
c - 3
```

I am getting

```
a - 1
a - 2
a - 3
b - 1
b - 2
b - 3
```

The query is the next one:

```
$hist = DB::table('codigo')
                ->join('llamada', 'codigo.idPaciente', '=', 'llamada.id_paciente')
                ->where('llamada.status_llamada', 'Finalizada')
                ->whereRaw('llamada.fecha_inicio > DATE_SUB(codigo.created_at, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)')
                ->whereRaw('llamada.fecha_inicio < DATE_ADD(codigo.created_at, INTERVAL 48 HOUR)')
                ->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('llamada.status_pago', '=', 'Sis')
                    ->orWhere('llamada.status_pago', '=', 'RedSis');
                })
                ->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('llamada.rec', '=', 1)
                    ->orWhereNotNull('llamada.ord')
                    ->orWhereNotNull('llamada.inter');
                })
                ->get();
```

The whereRaws clauses are for some rules that I need to get the correct result but I still get duplicates because sometimes multiple data enters in that range.

Any suggestions to improve this? Thanks!

Comment: Attach tables schemas

Comment: You're trying to get the same result as using Eloquent "with",  in your case, I would made a query for the table 'codigo' with 'llamada' in 'finalizada' state, then I'd make an iteration over the results and search the contents for 'llamada' in every iteration..